# Remove Border Color if Empty Value for Input

Tags: jquery

Need help to fix the issue with to remove border color on Input value.

Once user enter value in input border color will triger but when there is no value the border color should change to inherit color.

Thank you in advance.

```js
var minLength = 9;
var maxLength = 12;
$(document).ready(function(){
  var altNumberVal = $('#AlternateNumber');
    altNumberVal.on('keydown keyup change', function(){
        var char = $(this).val();
        var charLength = $(this).val().length;
        if(charLength < minLength){
          altNumberVal.css("border-color","red");
        }
      else if(charLength > maxLength){
            $(this).val(char.substring(0, maxLength));
        }
      else{
            altNumberVal.css("border-color","inherit");
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="AlternateNumber" placeholder="1234"></input>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add **condition** to check input is not empty `charLength > 0`

```
if(charLength < minLength && charLength > 0){}
```

```js
var minLength = 9;
var maxLength = 12;
$(document).ready(function(){
  var altNumberVal = $('#AlternateNumber');
    altNumberVal.on('keydown keyup change', function(){
        var char = $(this).val();
        var charLength = $(this).val().length;
        if(charLength < minLength && charLength > 0){
          altNumberVal.css("border-color","red");
        }
      else if(charLength > maxLength){
            $(this).val(char.substring(0, maxLength));
        }
      else{
          
            altNumberVal.css("border-color","inherit");
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="AlternateNumber" placeholder="1234"></input>
```